# How not to allow space between characters but allow space between the word with RegEx

Tags: regex, whitespace

I need to allow white spaces between words but not allow white spaces between characters.
for Example - 
"ABC X", "ABC XC" are allowed but "C X", "ABC X C" are not.

Requirement is "No letter followed by space followed by letter"

This needs to work for Spanish characters as well.

Should work in  - Java and Javascript
I've seen quite few questions (like [regular expression to allow spaces between words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472764/regular-expression-to-allow-spaces-between-words?rq=1))  but they either allow space or not allow space anywhere string.

I tried with - > `/(.)[^ ](.){1,}/` and `(\S\s+\S)`

I'm new to regEx and not sure how to proceed.
Will be great help if somebody can provide answer or some hint to achieve this.

Thanks,
YK

Comment: like this `^(?!.*\b\w\b\s+\w\b).*` ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Show us what you've tried, and tell us what language you're doing this in so we know the quirks of the regex parser, and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: What is a "word"?  Normally a single character counts as a word.  In your examples a single character seems sometimes acceptable and sometimes not.  You ought to clarify your requirements to get a good answer.

Comment: When you say word, do you mean something that I would find in a dictionary?

Comment: @AvinashRaj this one works for all except all specials Spanish characters. I need to support Spanish character as well

Comment: This one `(\s|^)\S\s+\S(\s|$)` supports Spanish characters as well but it's reverse of what I need. I think I will go this.

Comment: @YogeshK: Try `\b\S\s+\S\b`. In Java, you'd also need to use a `(?U)` modifier for the `\b` to work correctly and double escape the backslashes. What programming language are you using in fact? Both Java and JS? Do you really need 1 regex for two?

Comment: Can results of `(\s|^)\S\s+\S(\s|$)` be negated ?

Comment: @stribizhev yes, same RegEx will be used in JS(backbone.js) in front end and Java at back end.

Comment: Use `!` operator with `string.matches` in Java and `RegExp.test` in JS. Note that the whole string should match by Java `matches`, thus you would need to use something like `rx = ".*" + regex + ".*"`.

Comment: Thanks, all for your help. I will be using `(\s|^)\S\s+\S(\s|$)` with negative check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here.
`(\s|^)\S\s+\S(\s|$)` will match with all the criteria mentioned in the question.
As we need to restrict these format, negate the result of expression match.

Also for java, use `matcher.find()` instead of `matcher.matches()` to get desire result as it attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.