# How do I add white space in regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this code:

**CODE JS:**

```
const phone= /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[-]?(\d{3})[-]?(\d{4})$/;
```

After running this code has the following form

```
(123)132-1312
```

I want to add white space before the last parentheses as in the example below.

```
(123 )132-1312
```

Can you please tell me how to accept changes to the code so that white space?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

```
text = $(this).val().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1)$2-$3");
var testt=$(this).val().match(text);
```

I added this code to call here as add white space ...

Comment: I think there must be other questions asking the same thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472764/regular-expression-to-allow-spaces-between-words

Comment: Is the white space before last parenthesis qptional or required ?

Comment: Question is not clear now. What is the input and what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as you need:

```
/^\(?\s*(\d{3})\s*\)?[-]?(\d{3})[-]?(\d{4})$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on wether you always want the whitespace befor the closeing parenthesis or not your could go with:

`^\(?(\d{3}\s?)\)?[-]?(\d{3})[-]?(\d{4})$`

Background `\s` is for whitespaces. the `?` stands for 0 or 1 occurrance of the previous sign. if you use `+` it is one or more and `*` is for 0 or more occurrences of the previous sign.

To test your regex you can always use [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com)

Comment: I edited my post a little ... can you tell me please how do I change now?

Comment: try using this: `text = $(this).val().replace(/(\d{3}\s?)(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1 )$2-$3");`