# Regular expression to allow space between two string?

Tags: java, regex

I have following pattern to validate the String

```
pattern ="^[a-zA-Z0-9_{}#$\/\-\+@!?()^%$`~|:,.=\[\]]*$"
```

But here it is not accepting space between two string as well.Can someone please tell me what changes i have to do in above pattern so it will allow space between two string? But Space should not be allowed at the beginning and end of string.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472764/regular-expression-to-allow-spaces-between-words

Comment: `pattern ="(?=^[^\s]+(.*[^\s]+)*$)^[a-zA-Z0-9_{}#$\/\-\+@!?()^%$\`~|:,.=\[\]\s]*$"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)** and use `\s` for matching whitespace and `[^\s]` or `\S` for non-whitespace

```
pattern ="(?=^[^\s]+(.*[^\s]+)*$)^[a-zA-Z0-9_{}#$\/\-\+@!?()^%$`~|:,.=\[\]\s]*$"
```

**[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/jE9wE5/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]