# Regex - Find 2 words or more using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a simple regex to grab a string, It works fine with words like **HelloWorld** without space and how can i grab a words with space or more than 1 word like **Hello World**

**Text File**

```
FAN PS-2 is NOT PRESENT  #like this 'NOT PRESENT'
```

**Regex**

```
Value FAN_PS (\S*) # regex

Start 
  ^FAN PS is ${FAN_PS_1}
```

What should I change in my regex so I can grab more than 1 word?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regular expression to allow spaces between words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472764/regular-expression-to-allow-spaces-between-words)

Comment: i already try it, but it's doesn't work.. actually i'm new with regex so i'm a little confused with regex

Comment: So you have tried to replace `\S*` by `[\S\s]*` or even `.*`?

Comment: ohh.. i'm wrong, i replace this part `${RPS}`, not `\S*`... thanks @MalteHartwig, it's worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your regular expressions. The current expressions `\S*` match a string of **non-white-space characters**, so it is normal that you only get the first word.

If you **change `\S*` to `[\S ]*`**, you will get multiple words. You can even change it to the simpler `.*` if you do not care about certain characters.

Read [the python regex reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for information on different character classes.

Comment: how if only 2 words?

Comment: Just try it, it is really not that difficult. There is a quick approach here: https://regex101.com/r/RYLngN/. It can be done much nicer with a `{m}` quantifier (see documentation mentioned above) in case you want a certain number of words.

Comment: Ok, Thanks you for you're help