# JOI how to allow empty spaces and punctuation

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, vue.js, joi

I want to allow Joi to allow spaces/whitespaces in a title field of a form.

> Working tomorrow with Jude.

should be allowed as wel as

> Morningwalk

At this moment only the last one is validated as true. Here is my joi validation:

```js
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  title: Joi.string().alphanum().required().max(50),
```

I added [Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472764/regular-expression-to-allow-spaces-between-words/15473717#15473717) but without result.

```html
title: Joi.string().alphanum().required().max(50), regex(
  new RegExp('^\w+( +\w+)*$'))
```

What is the right way?

Comment: What if you replace `new RegExp('^\w+( +\w+)*$')` with `/^\w+( +\w+)*$/`?

Comment: still not allow spaces

Comment: Probably, you need to remove `.alphanum()`

Comment: Works. Now only add punctuation marks to regex. cheers

Comment: So, you mean `/^\w+(?:\W+\w+)*$/`?

Comment: Yes. I now searching for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.alphanum()` makes your check ignore whitespace. Also, when you define a regex using a constructor notation, you are using a string literal where backslashes are used to form string escape sequences and thus need doubling to form regex escape sequences. However, a regex literal notation is more convenient. Rather than writing `new RegExp('\\d')` you'd write `/\d/`.

So, you may use this to allow just whitespaces:

```
title: Joi.string().required().max(50), regex(/^\w+(?:\s+\w+)*$/)
```

However, you seem to want to not allow commas and allow all other punctuation.

Use

```
title: Joi.string().required().max(50), regex(/^\s*\w+(?:[^\w,]+\w+)*[^,\w]*$/)
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces (or, use `[^,\w]*` to match 0 or more chars other than comma and word chars)
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars (letters, digits or `_`, if you do not want `_`, replace with `[^\W_]`)
- `(?:[^\w,]+\w+)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `[^\w,]+` - 1 or more chars other than comma and word chars
  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `[^,\w]*` - 0 or more chars other than comma and word chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: We are almost there. punctuation is still not working.

Comment: @Tichel you have not asked about punctuation. You should update the question with what punctuation you want to match. Add valid/invalid cases.

Comment: @Tichel So, does `/^\w+(?:\W+\w+)*$/` work as expected?

Comment: @Tichel I see you also updated the example. But now, I do not quite understand what your intent is: what is NOT allowed? The pattern that will work for you is  `/^\W*\w+(?:\W+\w+)*\W*$/`, see https://regex101.com/r/1Q2EcU/1. Do you want to disallow an empty string and match any non-empty/non-blank string?

Comment: Wiktor, a comma ( , ) is now allowed. A dot ( . ) not. I am working on it.

Comment: @Tichel But you say `Working tomorrow with Jude.` is allowed and it contains a dot. What are the exact rules? Please add to the question. Also, see `/^\s*\w+(?:[^\w,]+\w+)*[^,\w]*$/` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Q2EcU/2)). You may fork this fiddle with your examples if you need more and faster help.

Comment: Let me know what exactly works so that I could adjust the answer and explain in detail.

Comment: the answer with the demo /^\s*\w+(?:[^\w,]+\w+)*[^,\w]*$/

Comment: Great, I  adjusted the answer and added the explanation. Please read the pattern details to see how you may adjust the pattern further if need be.