# HTML5 Input Pattern with 2 or more strings

Tags: html, regex, forms

i'm trying to use HTML5 Pattern in React.
My input code:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]" />
```

I want something like this: Pizza Texas or Spaghetti Bolognese. So i need pattern for strings with space between. But it would be good if pattern allows for 3 or more strings.

Comment: So you want to match a number of occurrences of `<string><whitespace>`? What have you tried, how did your attempt(s) fail?

Comment: Try this `pattern="[a-zA-Z ]"`

Comment: I'm tried with pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]" and pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2}", but this didn't work.

Comment: You are not adding space, see my comment.

Comment: pattern="[a-zA-Z ]" didn't work at all, "Pizza" "Pizza Texas" etc.

Comment: Note that you've not used any white-space characters in either of those examples, which you'd need to add for this. Would this be what you're looking for: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/o4hnwsc2/1/)? If so, then you're looking to use `<input pattern="^\w+( \w+)*$" />` which is taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15473717/82548 (which, in turn, makes this question a duplicate of that one).

Comment: Its pretty good, but i want only strings, in your demo i can write numbers

Comment: You can try this `[a-zA-Z ?]*` notice the space and question mark.

Comment: If you don't want to allow multiple spaces and also not at the start or end, you could use `[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*` See https://regex101.com/r/D89hI9/1 Note that adding the question mark in the character class would allow you to match it as a character.

Answer (score 0):

This represents one word:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)
```

This represents one word followed by a single space:

```
([a-zA-Z]+\s)
```

This represents two or more:

```
{2,}
```

All together:

```
([a-zA-Z]+\s){2,}([a-zA-Z]+)
```

***Two or more words followed by a single space then ending in a word.***

**Note:** If you want a minimum of two words then change `{2,}` to `{1,}`.

In the demo if only 1 or 2 words are entered then submitted there should be an error popup. If 3 or more words are entered and then submitted, the whole form should disappear.

```html
<form>
  <input name='threeWords' type='text' pattern='([a-zA-Z]+\s){2,}([a-zA-Z]+)' required>
  <input type='submit'>
</form>
```