# How to get text with both spaces and characters using a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I am trying to make a programme that goes to a Wikipedia list and lists all countries by how many people they have. I used a regular expression to get only the country names, however, country names that include spaces (DR Congo, South Korea, United Kingdom, etc) are  omitted.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pop = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_(United_Nations)")
soup = BeautifulSoup(pop.text, "html.parser")
f = soup.find_all("td", attrs={"align":"left"})

f = str(f)
x = re.findall("data-sort-value=\"\S+\"", flit)

print(x)
```

I know that "S" only counts non-space characters, but what should I replace "S" with to get both the spaces and the characters?

This is how the output looks:

```
['data-sort-value="China"', 'data-sort-value="India"', 'data-sort-value="Indonesia"', 'data-sort-value="Pakistan"', 'data-sort-value="Brazil"', 'data-sort-value="Nigeria"', 'data-sort-value="Bangladesh"', 'data-sort-value="Russia"', 'data-sort-value="Mexico"', 'data-sort-value="Japan"', 'data-sort-value="Ethiopia"', 'data-sort-value="Philippines"', 'data-sort-value="Egypt"', 'data-sort-value="Vietnam"', 'data-sort-value="Germany"', 'data-sort-value="Turkey"', 'data-sort-value="Iran"', 'data-sort-value="Thailand"', 'data-sort-value="France"', 'data-sort-value="Italy"', 'data-sort-value="Tanzania"', 'data-sort-value="Myanmar"', 'data-sort-value="Kenya"', 'data-sort-value="Colombia"', 'data-sort-value="Spain"', 'data-sort-value="Argentina"', 'data-sort-value="Uganda"', 'data-sort-value="Ukraine"', 'data-sort-value="Algeria"', 'data-sort-value="Sudan"', 'data-sort-value="Iraq"', 'data-sort-value="Afghanistan"', 'data-sort-value="Poland"', 'data-sort-value="Canada"', 'data-sort-value="Morocco"', 'data-sort-value="Uzbekistan"', 'data-sort-value="Peru"', 'data-sort-value="Malaysia"', 'data-sort-value="Angola"', 'data-sort-value="Mozambique"', 'data-sort-value="Yemen"', 'data-sort-value="Ghana"', 'data-sort-value="Nepal"', 'data-sort-value="Venezuela"', 'data-sort-value="Madagascar"', 'data-sort-value="Cameroon"', 'data-sort-value="Australia"', 'data-sort-value="Taiwan"', 'data-sort-value="Niger"', 'data-sort-value="Mali"', 'data-sort-value="Romania"', 'data-sort-value="Malawi"', 'data-sort-value="Chile"', 'data-sort-value="Kazakhstan"', 'data-sort-value="Zambia"', 'data-sort-value="Guatemala"', 'data-sort-value="Ecuador"', 'data-sort-value="Netherlands"', 'data-sort-value="Syria"', 'data-sort-value="Cambodia"', 'data-sort-value="Senegal"', 'data-sort-value="Chad"', 'data-sort-value="Somalia"', 'data-sort-value="Zimbabwe"', 'data-sort-value="Guinea"', 'data-sort-value="Rwanda"', 'data-sort-value="Benin"', 'data-sort-value="Tunisia"', 'data-sort-value="Belgium"', 'data-sort-value="Bolivia"', 'data-sort-value="Cuba"', 'data-sort-value="Haiti"', 'data-sort-value="Burundi"', 'data-sort-value="Greece"', 'data-sort-value="Portugal"', 'data-sort-value="Jordan"', 'data-sort-value="Azerbaijan"', 'data-sort-value="Sweden"', 'data-sort-value="Honduras"', 'data-sort-value="Hungary"', 'data-sort-value="Belarus"', 'data-sort-value="Tajikistan"', 'data-sort-value="Austria"', 'data-sort-value="Serbia"', 'data-sort-value="Switzerland"', 'data-sort-value="Israel"', 'data-sort-value="Togo"', 'data-sort-value="Laos"', 'data-sort-value="Paraguay"', 'data-sort-value="Bulgaria"', 'data-sort-value="Lebanon"', 'data-sort-value="Libya"', 'data-sort-value="Nicaragua"', 'data-sort-value="Kyrgyzstan"', 'data-sort-value="Turkmenistan"', 'data-sort-value="Singapore"', 'data-sort-value="Denmark"', 'data-sort-value="Finland"', 'data-sort-value="Slovakia"', 'data-sort-value="Congo"', 'data-sort-value="Norway"', 'data-sort-value="Palestine"', 'data-sort-value="Oman"', 'data-sort-value="Liberia"', 'data-sort-value="Ireland"', 'data-sort-value="Mauritania"', 'data-sort-value="Panama"', 'data-sort-value="Kuwait"', 'data-sort-value="Croatia"', 'data-sort-value="Moldova"', 'data-sort-value="Georgia"', 'data-sort-value="Eritrea"', 'data-sort-value="Uruguay"', 'data-sort-value="Mongolia"', 'data-sort-value="Armenia"', 'data-sort-value="Jamaica"', 'data-sort-value="Albania"', 'data-sort-value="Qatar"', 'data-sort-value="Lithuania"', 'data-sort-value="Namibia"', 'data-sort-value="Gambia"', 'data-sort-value="Botswana"', 'data-sort-value="Gabon"', 'data-sort-value="Lesotho"', 'data-sort-value="Slovenia"', 'data-sort-value="Guinea-Bissau"', 'data-sort-value="Latvia"', 'data-sort-value="Bahrain"', 'data-sort-value="Estonia"', 'data-sort-value="Mauritius"', 'data-sort-value="Cyprus"', 'data-sort-value="Eswatini"', 'data-sort-value="Djibouti"', 'data-sort-value="Fiji"', 'data-sort-value="Réunion"', 'data-sort-value="Comoros"', 'data-sort-value="Guyana"', 'data-sort-value="Bhutan"', 'data-sort-value="Macau"', 'data-sort-value="Montenegro"', 'data-sort-value="Luxembourg"', 'data-sort-value="Suriname"', 'data-sort-value="Maldives"', 'data-sort-value="Guadeloupe"', 'data-sort-value="Malta"', 'data-sort-value="Brunei"', 'data-sort-value="Belize"', 'data-sort-value="Bahamas"', 'data-sort-value="Martinique"', 'data-sort-value="Iceland"', 'data-sort-value="Vanuatu"', 'data-sort-value="Barbados"', 'data-sort-value="Mayotte"', 'data-sort-value="Guam"', 'data-sort-value="Curaçao"', 'data-sort-value="Kiribati"', 'data-sort-value="Grenada"', 'data-sort-value="Tonga"', 'data-sort-value="Aruba"', 'data-sort-value="Seychelles"', 'data-sort-value="Andorra"', 'data-sort-value="Dominica"', 'data-sort-value="Bermuda"', 'data-sort-value="Greenland"', 'data-sort-value="Monaco"', 'data-sort-value="Liechtenstein"', 'data-sort-value="Gibraltar"', 'data-sort-value="Palau"', 'data-sort-value="Anguilla"', 'data-sort-value="Tuvalu"', 'data-sort-value="Nauru"', 'data-sort-value="Montserrat"', 'data-sort-value="Niue"', 'data-sort-value="Tokelau"']
```

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472764/regular-expression-to-allow-spaces-between-words

Comment: For future reference you can use regex101.com to test and play with your regex

Answer (score 0):

`\D+` should work, non-digits include spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without regex. It's better to avoid regex when **scraping** html & instead utilize method's provided by `BeautifulSoup` to extract the contents.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = requests.get(
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_(United_Nations)'
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")

print(
    [x['data-sort-value']
     for x in soup.findAll("span", {"class": "datasortkey"})]
)
```

---

```
['Congo', 'Norway', 'Costa Rica', 'Palestine', 'Oman', 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands', ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a general solution to check for all names with multiple words, not just 2 words:

```
pattern_str = r'data-sort-value="(\S+(\s+\S+)*)"'
x = re.findall(pattern_str, flit)
```

This pattern string also matches names of 1 or more words, along with any names with one or more spaces.