# Regex for allowing alphanumeric and space

Tags: javascript, regex

I am searching for a regular expression for allowing alphanumeric and spaces in JavaScript. I tried Googling but wasn't able to find that. For alphanumeric i am using '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just add your space. ^[\w\ ]+$

Comment: \w is shorthand for alphanumeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a space; `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$`

Increase your google-fu: https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+allow+spaces

I'm not sure how or what you tried googling but there's heaps of results to your question... Including this [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472764/regular-expression-to-allow-spaces-between-words) where your question has been answered in great detail.

Comment: When I am using this reg expression i was able to enter space at beginning

Comment: Beginning or end, doesn't matter. Just add it in the list (or the expression).

Answer (score 1):

You might be surprised but you literally only had to add a space in between the square brackets like so:

```
'^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$'
```

RegExp is challenging but I have found a resource by google that can be quite helpful [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en&ref_topic=1034375).

Comment: When I am using this reg expression i was able to enter space at beginning