# How to write a regex pattern which accepts space in between words?

Tags: php, regex

I am very new to the regex patterns. I am developing one api which accepts the user value(status), based on the status it will perform the filtering operation upto this it's working fine.

Now what my requirement is I want to accept the `value` based on:

1. if the string contains multiple words it should be separated by `space` only not other symbols(/_) .
2. Both caps and small letters are allowed .

**Valid scenarios:**

1. Ready to dispatch
2. ReaDy To Dispatch
3. cancelled
4. CanceLled

**Invalid scenarios:**

1. Ready_to_dispatch
2. Ready-to-Dispatch

   ```
   $pattern=[a-zA-Z];
   $validation=preg_match($pattern,$request->status);
   if($validation){
     //My logic executes if it matches the pattern
   }
   ```

Comment: See [Regular expression to allow spaces between words](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15472764/3832970)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to allow spaces between words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472764/regular-expression-to-allow-spaces-between-words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the pattern you could repeat the character class one or more times, and as only a space is allowed between the words, optionally repeat the same character class preceded by a space.

```
^[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*$
```

You could update the code to placing the pattern between quotes and add delimiters `/` around the pattern.

```
$pattern="/^[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*$/";
$validation = preg_match($pattern,$request->status);

if($validation){
    //My logic executes if it matches the pattern
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your `$pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$"` or just add a space only.
*$pattern* add under quota:

```
$pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$";
$validation=preg_match($pattern,$request->status);
if($validation){
  //My logic executes if it matches the pattern
}
```